# How to remove outer collection from a collection of collections?

Tags: clojure

How can I transform `'((1 2 3) (4 5 6))` into `'(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)`?

Concretely, if I have the following collection:

```
(def coll '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

And I want to pass both `'(1 2 3)` and `'(4 5 6)` as arguments to a method, how can `coll` be transformed into two lists?

For example, in

```
(map list ?? coll)
```

what implementation of `??` would lead to

```
'((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Which is the result of `(map list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))`.

What I tried is:

`(flatten coll)` does not work since it leads to one list `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`.

Unquote splicing as in `~@coll` leads to

> Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/unquote-splicing.

And mapping with quote as in `(map #(quote %) coll)` leads to something like `(p1__10109# p1__10109#)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation is often called [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). In clojure, you can do it thus:

```
(apply map list coll) ;((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why this works and `~@` doesn't?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Unquote splicing only works within syntax quotes, AFAIK.